# SQLAlchemy -Comparison between existing column value and potential update value

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy model which I'm updating with data from an XML file. I want to be notified where the new value differs from the old one.

I tried the simple:

```
if ModelInstance.Field <> NewValue:
    print "Field has changed from", ModelInstance.Field, "to", NewValue
```

But this doesn't work in many cases because the types of the variables differ and would also not work if I added triggers to the model that changed the value on assignment.

So, what I'm asking is how I can compare the value of the field now with the value the field would hold if I assigned it the new value.

To clarify following the comment from DrColossus - I might read "1.0" as a string from the source file and the model might have an Integer type column containing the value 1. If you compare the two they aren't the same but if you were to assign "1.0" into the column the value would end up the same and it's that kind of thing I'm trying to detect.

Comment: Why do they differ? Do you mean one is a string, the other one an int? Does converting the type work (e.g. `str("4")` to get integer value `4`)? Or do you mean the values differ in general like it is "foo" but is "bar"?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want an [attribute set event](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.AttributeEvents.set).